# how to do a continuous sum with python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, function, sum

I would like to do the same in python pandas as shown on the picture.

[pandas image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsHLT.png)

This is sum function where the first cell is fixed and the formula calculates "**continuous sum**".

I tried to create pandas data frame however I did not manage to do this exactly.

Comment: perhaps show your code so far

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to [pandas cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)
For example:

```html
df['NEW_COLUMN_CUMULATED'] = df['OLD_COLUMN'].cumsum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.cumsum()` to achieve what you want:

`import pandas as pd`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10, 20, 30])
print(df.cumsum())
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you shared, use [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with [`pandas.Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame({'Nuber': [10.0, np.NaN, 20.0, np.NaN, np.NaN, 10.0, np.NaN, np.NaN, 30.0]})

df["Sum cont"]= df["Nuber"].cumsum().ffill()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

   Nuber  Sum cont
0   10.0      10.0
1    NaN      10.0
2   20.0      30.0
3    NaN      30.0
4    NaN      30.0
5   10.0      40.0
6    NaN      40.0
7    NaN      40.0
8   30.0      70.0
```

##### # Edit :

If you read the data from an Excel spreadsheet, use this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("python inport.xlsx")
df["Sum cont"]= df["Nuber"].cumsum().ffill()
```

Or this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = (
        pd.read_excel("python inport.xlsx")
            .assign(Sum_Count= lambda x: x["Nuber"].cumsum().ffill())
      )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works nicely. The only thing is that the data frame is imported from excel with `pd.read_excel`.
I was trying to  make it work with your code so far no success. The main issue is with `df["Nuber“]` which is not definied in the excel import the way you did it in your example. I woudl be gratefull for a help. @abokey

Comment: Can you show with a screenshot how looks like your Excel spreadsheet ? The position of the header, the name of the sheet, .. etc. Is it the same as this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsHLT.png ?

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kvRUDF9iaRnQfHsSU9I03VlPULPLaaDp4_ZU0lF-5lk/edit?usp=sharing), @abokey

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, check it out ;)

Comment: I tried both I donť know what could be possible wrong. Se the shared file. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QXoUNaf7bBT1MWefl2R9q8J9gMAdwysQ?usp=sharing) @abokey

Comment: That's what I did, I downloaded your file and the code I shared in the edit works fine for me. What error do you get?

Comment: I shared with you the complete jupyter notebook screenshot, can you open it? @abokey, thank you

Comment: There is some extra whitespaces in the columns `Action` and `Nuber` in your spreadsheet. I suggest you to clean the header in Excel or use `df.columns= df.columns.str.strip()` before calling `cumsum`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sum` function in pandas for specific range of rows using index of start and end row:

```
df.iloc[0:5].sum()
```

The sum of the rows with index values between `0` and `5` (not including 5)

Output:

```
30
```